# How to pass dynamic values to create a multi user environment in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I've recorded a set of requests from our app using Jmeter, our web service is designed so that everytime a user id (fb id) is sent to the server it will be treated as a user.

My recorded set of scripts have a "send files with request" option enabled and have a binary file(.binary) attached to it, I need to create a load test scenario where I can send requests with different user IDs to create multi-user scenario. What should I do to get this done? Will it be enough that I pass the user ids a parameter and get it done?

Since the request uses a post method with this binary file being send along, should I do something to pass values to the binary file?

Can someone show me an example as on  how to implement this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned steps will help you achieve the above scenario:

- Do correlation for dynamic parameters
  http://apache-jmeter.blogspot.com/2011/12/correlation-regular-expression.html
- Use CSV for login credentials
  http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/
- Add a Cookie Manager to your script

hope this will help